# AWS logfiles location

Tags: logging, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm having some touble with my S3 bucket while uploading. To debug it I've enabled logging on the S3 bucket, and store it to logs/. I assume I would see a folder ./logs/ in the targeted bucket, however the folder is nowhere to be found. I really need those logs before I can continue debugging, does anyone here have an idea where it can be found? Unfortunately we don't have the support level to ask such questions to Amazon.

Hope you guys can help me!

Thanks in advance,

Jimmy

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you "Grant the Amazon S3 Log Delivery group write permission on the bucket where you want the access logs saved"?

See docs in: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html

See how in: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/enable-logging-console.html